# AFNetworking, getting 401 with proper token

Tags: ios, rest, afnetworking

I'm making a request on https://www.ez-point.com/api/v1/ezpoints with a proper token using a Chrome Rest Client. I'm properly getting the result. However, when using `AFNetworking`, I'm getting a 401.

Here is my code snippet:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://www.ez-point.com/api/v1/"];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url ];
[httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:@"xxxxxxxxxx"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/ezpoints" parameters:nil];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"success");
}
failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"Error");
```

Here is the error:

```
2013-10-29 08:51:38.908 EZ-POINT[4944:c07] I restkit:RKLog.m:34 RestKit logging initialized...
2013-10-29 08:51:39.189 EZ-POINT[4944:c07] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:180 GET 'https://www.ez-point.com/ezpoints'
2013-10-29 08:51:41.908 EZ-POINT[4944:c07] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:209 GET 'https://www.ez-point.com/ezpoints' (401 Unauthorized) [2.7191 s]: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 401" UserInfo=0x1052ef40 {AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest https://www.ez-point.com/ezpoints>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.ez-point.com/ezpoints, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 401, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xac54520>}
2013-10-29 08:51:41.908 EZ-POINT[4944:c07] Error
```

Answer (score 1):

Its working with the following code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://www.ez-point.com/api/v1/ezpoints"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setValue:@"4f62fab9c91c46ad971cc2ae4a32bb6f" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
    [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[JSON objectForKey:@"status"]);
        }
            failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                NSLog(@"%@", @"Error");
        }];
    [operation start];
```